# drop columns in pandas dataframe based on mask

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  dataframe with various number of values in each columns.  I created a mask that tells me how many values in each column with the following code from another post > I get the following results

```
count_year_mask = df_mth_return.notnull().sum()
results in series like this
AAPL US Equity     312
GOOGL US Equity    161
GOOG US Equity      45
MSFT US Equity     312
AMZN US Equity     248
FB US Equity        68
```

I then want to delete all the columns in df_mth_return that are LESS THAN 180 from the above series.  I want the DF to only have columns with > 180 numbers.  So GOOGL, GOOG and FB would be eliminated. I tried this code and got the following error

```
df_mth_return.drop(np.where(count_year_mask<180))
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 3)
```

This seems like a simple mask so not sure what I am doing wrong.  Please help if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter columns with `loc`:

```
df_mth_return.loc[:, count_year_mask>=180]
```

Or:

```
df_mth_return.loc[:, ~count_year_mask<180]
```

Comment: appreciate your help.  ty